# How to convert Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>> and TKey to Expression<Func<TSource,bool>>?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

`IQueryable.OrderBy` receives a key selector expression `Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>>`. `IQueryable.Single` receives a comparison expression `Expression<Func<TSource,bool>>`.

Can I convert an `Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>>` and a `TKey` value into an `Expression<Func<TSource,bool>>`? For example, if I have the key selector expression `x => e => e.Id`, I want the comparison expression `x => e => e.Id == value`.

I wrote this method:

```
public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> KeyComparator(TKey key) =>
            Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(Expression.Equal(KeySelector, Expression.Constant(key)))
```

This makes the compiler happy. I can write stuff like `someQueryable.Single(KeyComparator(key))`. But when it runs I get this error:

> The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Func`2[TSource,System.Int32]' and 'System.Int32'.

...where `TSource` is my actual class name. That seems to say that equality comparison is not defined for `int` and `int`. Huh?

Comment: These types are not related at all. Neither are `OrderBy` and `Single`. For example, what would the result be, if `(Foo x) => x.SomeStringProperty` is converted into an expression that takes a `Foo` and returns `bool`, given a string `"Bar"`?

Comment: But how? Say I have an expression tree like `x => x.SomeIntegerKey`, what would you do? So you want to additionally have a value and then turn it into `x => x.SomeIntegerKey == yourDesiredValue` or similar?

Comment: You could merge two expressions, a property accessor; `x => x.Prop` and an operator that compares that type and returns bool; `y => y == 0` into `x => x.Prop == 0`. But you would need to explain what you are trying to do *and why*.

Comment: The point of the argument you pass to `OrderBy` is that, from each item in the list, you generate a value and then you sort the list by those values. If the value you generate is type `bool` then you have what you're asking for. The thing is, it seems like you are asking this question for reason that doesn't really make sense, given your reference to `Single`. As suggested above, you need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, exactly.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The problem is very simple: I want to write a key selector expression and derive a key comparator expression from it because DRY. This is in an abstract class where the implementor only has to write the key selector expression and a couple other things and they get a few thousand lines of generated code for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to convert the expression to be like a predicate that compares the `TKey` (what the expression evaluates to) to another given `TKey`.

You should get the [`Body`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.body?view=net-7.0) of the lambda expression, which is what your code is missing, to create a `==` expression. You cannot compare the lambda expression itself with a `TKey`. The `Body` refers to everything on the right of `=>` of the lambda.

You should also include the original lambda's parameters, when putting the new `==` expression into a `Expression.Lambda`.

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> Convert<TSource, TKey>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> expr,
    TKey key
) => Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(expr.Body, Expression.Constant(key)),
        expr.Parameters
    );
```

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert((String s) => s.Length, 1));
// s => (s.Length == 1)
```

Comment: I think this gets me a step closer, but the result is not translatable. My `expr` is something like `o => o.CountryId`, and the error message says the expression `'o'` is not translatable.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede `Compile` can translate it. Not sure why EF can't. *shrugs*

Comment: I wrote a test controller as a minimal example and confirmed that 1) this is the correct answer, and 2) something else about my code is preventing EF from translating it, because it works perfectly in my test controller.