# Why can't EF translate this Expression when it's derived from a virtual property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, expression-trees, ef-core-7.0

I want to define an `Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>> KeyExpr` such as you would pass to `IQueryable.OrderBy`, and then combine it with a `TKey` value to derive an `Expression<Func<TSource,bool>> WithKeyExpr` such as you would pass to `IQueryable.Single`. I learned how to do this in [another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76160919/how-to-convert-expressionfunctsource-tkey-and-tkey-to-expressionfunctsourc) and confirmed that the accepted answer works.

The problem I'm encountering now is that EF cannot translate `WithKeyExpr` when `KeyExpr` is virtual. As a baseline, I wrote a controller that defines these expressions non-virtually:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private ErpContext Db { get; }

    private Expression<Func<Country, int>> KeyExpr { get; } = e => e.CountryId;

    private Expression<Func<Country, bool>> WithKeyExpr(int key) =>
        Expression.Lambda<Func<Country, bool>>(Expression.Equal(KeyExpr.Body, Expression.Constant(key)), KeyExpr.Parameters);

    public TestController(ErpContext db)
    {
        Db = db;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("[action]")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Country>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Country>> GetAsync()
    {
        return await Db.Countries.OrderBy(KeyExpr).ToListAsync();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}/[action]")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Country), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        var country = await Db.Countries.SingleOrDefaultAsync(WithKeyExpr(id));
        return country == null ? NotFound() : Ok(country);
    }
}
```

Both of these controller actions work perfectly.

To reproduce the error I'm getting, I made `KeyExpr` abstract. Everything else, including `WithKeyExpr`, is defined in exactly the same way as before:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public abstract class TestControllerBase : ControllerBase
{
    private ErpContext Db { get; }

    protected abstract Expression<Func<Country, int>> KeyExpr { get; }
    private Expression<Func<Country, bool>> WithKeyExpr(int key) =>
        Expression.Lambda<Func<Country, bool>>(Expression.Equal(KeyExpr.Body, Expression.Constant(key)), KeyExpr.Parameters);

    public TestControllerBase(ErpContext db)
    {
        Db = db;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("[action]")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Country>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Country>> GetAsync()
    {
        return await Db.Countries.OrderBy(KeyExpr).ToListAsync();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Country), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [Route("{id}/[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        var country = await Db.Countries.SingleOrDefaultAsync(WithKeyExpr(id));
        return country == null ? NotFound() : Ok(country);
    }
}
```

Then I derived a concrete controller:

```
public class TestController : TestControllerBase
{
    public TestController(ErpContext db) : base(db) { }

    protected override Expression<Func<Country, int>> KeyExpr => o => o.CountryId;
}
```

`Get()` still works, demonstrating that EF can translate the virtual `KeyExpr`. But `Get(int)` does *not* work; EF cannot translate the `WithKeyExpr` derived from the virtual `KeyExpr`. The error is:

> The LINQ expression 'o' could not be translated.

Why can EF no longer translate `WithKeyExpr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
protected override Expression<Func<Country, int>> KeyExpr => o => o.CountryId;
```

This will return a new expression instance for each call to the `KeyExpr` property, so `o` in the `KeyExpr.Parameters` and `o` used in the `KeyExpr.Body` will be different instances of `ParameterExpression` (with the same parameter name) which leads to the error in the question. One way to fix it is to change the child class to:

```cs
public class TestController : TestControllerBase
{
    // ...

    protected override Expression<Func<Country, int>> KeyExpr { get; } = o => o.CountryId;
}
```

Or change `WithKeyExpr` to:

```cs
private Expression<Func<Country, bool>> WithKeyExpr(int key)
{
    var keyExpr = KeyExpr;
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Country, bool>>(Expression.Equal(keyExpr.Body, Expression.Constant(key)),
        keyExpr.Parameters);
}
```

Comment: That indeed fixes it. Since the compiler accepts an implementation that EF won't, I'll have to come up with some way to prevent myself or someone else from doing that. Maybe require the expression as a constructor parameter and write it to the property's backing field...

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede another way is to fix the `WithKeyExpr` so it calls `KeyExpr` only one time and saves the result into interim variable (updated the code).